# Attempting to enable X-Pack for Logstash monitoring with Metricbeat

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack, elk, metricbeat

I want to use metricbeat to monitor my logstash pipelines. I understand it is even possible to see it on the UI in Kibana. Below is the reference I am using

*Collect Logstash monitoring data with Metricbeat*

https://[www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/monitoring-with-metricbeat.html](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/monitoring-with-metricbeat.html)

I am trying to run a simple windows powershell command to enable xpack as defined in the documentation

PS> cd C:\ProgramData\Elastic\Beats\metricbeat\modules.d

PS > .\metricbeat.exe modules enable logstash-xpack

It returns error

> modules : The term 'modules' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
>
> .\metricbeat.exe : The term '.\metricbeat.exe' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or
>   operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try
>   again.

Comment: This is a path error, you are in the wrong directory, try to run the command from the directory which has the `metricbeat.exe` file.

Comment: I was missing the executable file for some reason. I re downloaded metricbeat and now I have it. It is working.